# Implementation of CRL in Cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I am working on a Cocoa application which has to perform both client to server and client to client communications. I am planning to implement CRL (Certificate Revocation List) in the `NSURLConnection` when using the HTTPS protocol.

I did not find enough documentation on the same. A pointer to this information would be of great help.

Comment: What part of the CRL implementation are you trying to do yourself?  Are you keeping your own list or using a server? If you're keeping a list, what data is in it (Fingerprint, entire certificate, something else)?

Comment: I am a new bee to CRL implementation. So far, I have worked with regular NSURLConnection calls. But here, I need to validate client certificate using CRL.